# Why git log change the author filter syntax only in one device

Tags: git, zsh, git-log

I'm here to ask about a very strange problem I ran into with the git log:

I have 2 devices, both with zsh terminal, on which I have to run a git log filtering the authors by email.

The command I run is:

```bash
git log --author="\(email1@gmail.com\)\|\(email2@gmail.com\)" --after=2023-03-01
```

Only now, in an inexplicable way, on the second device has this format stopped working while it has started to accept this:

```bash
git log --author="(email1@gmail.com)|(email2@gmail.com)" --after=2023-03-01
```

Since this command is standard, I would like to understand why the syntax has changed on the second device and how to go back, or simply force one of the 2

Thanks in advance!

PS
Owr git version is: `git version 2.41.0`, but the same problem appears with 2.39, boot installed with `brew`.
The zsh version is: `zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)`

And finally the result of `git config --list` for each device are:
[image: Meld diff of each git config]

EDIT_1:
@knittl
After digit `set -x`, the output is
This is the output result:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-di-user crm % git log --author="\(user1@gmail.com\)\|\(user2@gmail.com\)" --after=2023-03-27 --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: 
+__vsc_preexec:1> PS1='%n@%m %1~ %# ' 
+__vsc_preexec:2> PS2='%_> ' 
+__vsc_preexec:3> [ -n '' ']'
+__vsc_preexec:6> __vsc_in_command_execution=1 
+__vsc_preexec:7> __vsc_current_command='git log --author="\(user1@gmail.com\)\|\(user2@gmail.com\)" --after=2023-03-27 --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: ' 
+__vsc_preexec:8> __vsc_command_output_start
+__vsc_command_output_start:1> printf '\e]633;C\a'
+__vsc_command_output_start:2> __vsc_escape_value 'git log --author="\(user1@gmail.com\)\|\(user2@gmail.com\)" --after=2023-03-27 --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: '
+__vsc_escape_value:1> emulate -L zsh
+__vsc_escape_value:4> local 'LC_ALL=C' 'str=git log --author="\(user1@gmail.com\)\|\(user2@gmail.com\)" --after=2023-03-27 --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: ' i byte token 'out='
...
...
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 142
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=: 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ : '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ : '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=: 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=: 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
...
...
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 142
+__vsc_escape_value:21> print -r 'git log --author="\\(user1@gmail.com\\)\\|\\(user2@gmail.com\\)" --after=2023-03-27 --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: '
+__vsc_command_output_start:2> printf '\e]633;E;%s;%s\a' 'git log --author="\\(user1@gmail.com\\)\\|\\(user2@gmail.com\\)" --after=2023-03-27 --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: ' a601b767-d5fd-47a1-834e-6eaba4a7799d
+/bin/zsh:10> git log '--author=\(user1@gmail.com\)\|\(user2@gmail.com\)' '--after=2023-03-27' --oneline --name-only '--pretty=format:'
+__vsc_precmd:1> local __vsc_status=0                                                                                                                                                            
+__vsc_precmd:2> [ -z 1 ']'
+__vsc_precmd:7> __vsc_command_complete 0
+__vsc_command_complete:1> [[ 'git log --author="\(user1@gmail.com\)\|\(user2@gmail.com\)" --after=2023-03-27 --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: ' ==  ]]
+__vsc_command_complete:4> printf '\e]633;D;%s\a' 0
+__vsc_command_complete:6> __vsc_update_cwd
+__vsc_update_cwd:1> __vsc_escape_value /Users/a469952/Documents/CRMT_Italia
+__vsc_escape_value:1> emulate -L zsh
+__vsc_escape_value:4> local 'LC_ALL=C' 'str=/Users/a469952/Documents/CRMT_Italia' i byte token 'out='
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i = 0
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 36
+__vsc_escape_value:7> byte=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:10> [ / '=' '\' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:12> [ / '=' ';' ']'
+__vsc_escape_value:15> token=/ 
+__vsc_escape_value:18> out+=/ 
...
Change only out+= ....
...
+__vsc_escape_value:6> ++i 
+__vsc_escape_value:6> i < 36
+__vsc_escape_value:21> print -r /Users/a469952/Documents/CRMT_Italia
+__vsc_update_cwd:1> printf '\e]633;P;Cwd=%s\a' /Users/a469952/Documents/CRMT_Italia
+__vsc_precmd:8> __vsc_current_command='' 
+__vsc_precmd:11> [ -n 1 ']'
+__vsc_precmd:13> __vsc_update_prompt
+__vsc_update_prompt:1> __vsc_prior_prompt='%n@%m %1~ %# ' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:2> __vsc_prior_prompt2='%_> ' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:3> __vsc_in_command_execution='' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:4> PS1=+__vsc_update_prompt:4> __vsc_prompt_start
+__vsc_prompt_start:1> printf '\e]633;A\a'
+__vsc_update_prompt:4> PS1=+__vsc_update_prompt:4> __vsc_prompt_end
+__vsc_prompt_end:1> printf '\e]633;B\a'
+__vsc_update_prompt:4> PS1=$'%{\C-[]633;A\C-G%}%n@%m %1~ %# %{\C-[]633;B\C-G%}' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:5> PS2=+__vsc_update_prompt:5> __vsc_continuation_start
+__vsc_continuation_start:1> printf '\e]633;F\a'
+__vsc_update_prompt:5> PS2=+__vsc_update_prompt:5> __vsc_continuation_end
+__vsc_continuation_end:1> printf '\e]633;G\a'
+__vsc_update_prompt:5> PS2=$'%{\C-[]633;F\C-G%}%_> %{\C-[]633;G\C-G%}' 
+__vsc_update_prompt:6> [ -n '' ']'
```

Comment: different terminal and git configs and versions? we need them to have something to work with i guess

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double quotes. Your shell might interpret those parentheses. You can also run `set -x` once to have the shell show each command as it is executed (after expansion/substitution done by the shell)

Comment: Are you sure the shell is still zsh on the second device? In Bash, you don't need to escape `(` in a quoted string; running `echo "\(hello\)"` will output the literal string `\(hello\)`. That behavior would cause the problem you've described.

Comment: we have already tried to replace the quotes, but nothing, the only thing that worked, even if it is not desired, was to remove the backslashes

Comment: @larsks, yes, i open for test a bash shell in the second device, but the output was the same. More over, the `\(` and `\)` solution is native from bash, not zsh

Comment: Your config screenshot (please use _text_, not images of text) shows `grep.extendedregexp=true` – does that ring a bell?

Comment: That was my test, i try to activate and then deactivate it, but nothing change